# how to customize the Dialog Box

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, dialog

In my app I am using a dialog as shown in figure. in this dialog I have a listview in a linerLayout now I want to customize this box. I mean I want to change font size of the the title "Profile Options", and make a divider between tow elements.how can I do this please guide[image]

Comment: What did you try already? Possibly worth a read: [Creating a Custom Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your own layout and set it as

**dialog.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);**

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Answer (score 0):

Please disable the title of dialog and add the title to you content view.These way you customize the dialog title